# Apache camel - SQL to CSV

Tags: java, xml, csv, apache-camel, blueprint-osgi

I have tried to convert sql result to csv file
this is the route (bluprint.xml):

```
<route id="extractfromafbl">
  <from uri="timer:foo?period=10000"/>
  <to uri="sql:select * from performances?dataSource=afbl_source"/>
  <to uri="bean:ngtrend.afbl2afc.transformer?method=tocsv(Exchange)"/>
  <log message="${body}"/>
</route>
```

This is transformer class to create csv format:

```
    public class transformer {
            public void tocsv(Exchange exchange)
            {
                StringBuilder csv = new StringBuilder();
                List received = exchange.getIn().getBody(List.class);
                for (int i = 0; i < received.size(); i++) 
                 {
                   Map<String,Object> row = (Map<String,Object>) received.get(i);
                   csv.append(row.get("id"));
                   csv.append(",").append(row.get("lastname"));
                   csv.append(",").append(row.get("firstname"));
                   csv.append("\r");
                 }
            }
        }
```

in this case I should know the name of fields (like id, lastname ...) and I want to use an index 
instead because the table or fields can change.

How can I use index instead of name fields ?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Claus How can i use index instead of name fields ? if is not possible haw can i convert to csv ?

Answer (score 4):

I know you can make the code above work with some tweaks, but I thought I would make a suggestion that could make this whole problem way easier for you.  The Camel SQL component lets you automatically map your database response back to an Object.  Syntax is like this:

```
from("sql:select * from performances?dataSource=afbl_source?outputType=SelectList&outputClass=com.myapp.MyDatabaseModel")
```

Once you have this setup you will get an object in your camel body of a

```
List<MyDatabaseModel>
```

At this point you can leverage a camel component called Bindy.  It will let you have an Object represent a CSV file.  The way you would bind this is with a few annotations on your database model so it can also represent your csv output.

```
@CsvRecord(isOrdered = true)
public Class MyDatabaseModel{

   @DataField(pos = 1, position = 11)
   private int orderNr;

   @DataField(pos = 2, position = 10)
   private String clientNr;

   ...
}
```

The call to Bindy would be setup something like this:

```
// Camel 2.15 or older (configure by package name)
BindyCsvDataFormat bindy = new BindyCsvDataFormat("com.myapp");
// Camel 2.16 onwards (configure by class name)
BindyCsvDataFormat bindy = new BindyCsvDataFormat(com.myapp.MyDatabaseModel.class);

.marshal(bindy)
```

Bringing it all together you can break your project down into 2 lines of camel and 1 java object for this task.  "Full camel below"

```
from("sql:select * from performances?dataSource=afbl_source?outputType=SelectList&outputClass=com.myapp.MyDatabaseModel")
    .marshal(bindy);
```

I think I should also mention if you don't want to worry too much about configuration of your csv order you can actually skip the whole annotation process and simply do:

```
marshal().csv();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The problem is that i dont know the fields names. I have to convert the list to csv format regardless the sql result .

Comment: You might be able to leverage the features of your database itself.  Most databases allow you to export a table as a CSV.  You could further simplify this by leveraging that feature as a Stored Procedure and scheduling it so you wouldn't have much code to maintain.  That is also another option

Answer (score 0):

Find a small snippet to show that it will not work as you whish.

```
List<Map<String, Object>> received = new ArrayList<>();
Map<String, Object> rowOne = new HashMap<>();
rowOne.put("id", 42);
rowOne.put("lastname", "Doe");
rowOne.put("firstname", "John");
Map<String, Object> rowTwo = new HashMap<>();
rowTwo.put("id", 23);
rowTwo.put("lastname", "Doe");
rowTwo.put("firstname", "Jane");
received.add(rowOne);
received.add(rowTwo);
StringBuilder csv = new StringBuilder();
for (Map<String, Object> i : received) {
    StringJoiner line = new StringJoiner(",");
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> j : i.entrySet()) {
        line.add(j.getValue().toString());
    }
    csv.append(line.toString()).append("\n");
}
System.out.println(csv);
```

output

```
John,42,Doe
Jane,23,Doe
```

The order of the values depends on the name of the column and the type of the `Map`.

If you use a `TreeMap` you might force the names of the columns returned by the SQL statement to be in the order you want to output them (I would not suggest to do so)

See this small snippet to show the idea

```
List<Map<String, Object>> received = new ArrayList<>();
Map<String, Object> rowOne = new TreeMap<>();
rowOne.put("1id", 42);
rowOne.put("2lastname", "Doe");
rowOne.put("3firstname", "John");
Map<String, Object> rowTwo = new TreeMap<>();
rowTwo.put("id", 23);
rowTwo.put("lastname", "Doe");
rowTwo.put("firstname", "Jane");
received.add(rowOne);
received.add(rowTwo);
StringBuilder csv = new StringBuilder();
for (Map<String, Object> i : received) {
    StringJoiner line = new StringJoiner(",");
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> j : i.entrySet()) {
        line.add(j.getValue().toString());
    }
    csv.append(line.toString()).append("\n");
}
System.out.println(csv);
```

output

```
42,Doe,John
Jane,23,Doe
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm just getting started with Camel so perhaps there's another way but I'm able to dump from a table to a CSV file without any knowledge of the field names with:

```
CsvDataFormat csv = new CsvDataFormat();
csv.setQuoteMode("ALL");

from("sql:select * from MY_TEST_TABLE?dataSource=oracleDataSource&useIterator=false").marshal(csv).to("file:///tmp?fileName=MY_TEST_FILE.csv");
```

and add the dependency

```
    <dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
<artifactId>camel-csv</artifactId>
<version>version</version>
```